# Accessing a shared folder using other credentials with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, shared-folders

I was at a client office trying to connect to a shared drive on their network but was greeted by a

**`"you do not have permission to access"`** error!

Couldn't find any way to enter the required credentials as this message didn't had any other options. Tried to map the drive, selected the option to enter the correct credentials (with `\\HOST\user`) but it wouldn't work at all. The worst thing in all of this is that my coworker who is using `OS X` has been able to connect to that drive without any problem, he clicked on it, entered the credentials and could open the folder!

The folder is shared by a Windows Small Business Server 2008 machine.

Answer (score 11):

The first rule to remember is that with almost all versions of Windows, in a single session, you can only be authenticated to a server with a single set of credentials.  So if you already had a mapped drive, a shortcut on the desktop or something else, then you are already authenticated to that server.

One think you can do is drop down to a shell prompt, then use the command `net use`.  The `net use` command all by itself will list your current connections.  Use `net use /delete \\server\share` to delete any existing connections to that server.  Once all your connections are gone simply use `net use /user:username \\server/share`.  See the output of `net use /?` for more help.

Comment: Cool, I didn't thought about that one! It will take a while before I get back there to try this solution, but I'll make sure to mark this answer accordingly if it work. Sorry that I'm rarely around a MS network!

Comment: Kind of crazy that Windows shared folder feature hasn't evolved much in the past 15+ years, I remember having the same kind of problems back then!

Answer (score 0):

Most authentication use `"<server>\<username>"` not `"\\<server>\<username>"`. The double backslash is only used for UNC file paths.