# How can I change my user credentials for accessing shared folders from a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, network-shares, shared-folders

In our office we are using shared folders at different hierarchy levels. I need to jump between (for example) being "martin" and "admin". Also this is useful when I make a typo in my password and need to start over without re-booting my machine.

In Windows it took me a long time to find, but I can use this command (for example to drop my credentials for a NAS:
net use \192.168.0.nnn /del

Then I restart my File-Explorer and when I access a shared folder I get asked again for my user-name and pw.

Now I am searching for the equivalent when working on a Linux machine please (mostly OpenSuse Leap and some Ubuntu in our office).

When I search for this problem, I find many pages explaining how to change the status/access-rights of a given folder; but nothing on how to change my user for accessing such shared folders, sorry.

Comment: If you want to see the relevance, look at the Windows version of this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/411684/accessing-a-shared-folder-using-other-credentials-with-windows-7?rq=1